# What is the arcade equivalent to "If value in list" in the Visualizations profile

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-portal, arcade

What is the arcade equivalent to Python evaluating the conditional statement "If value in list":

```
fueltype = 'JP5'
fueltype_list = ['F24', 'JP10', 'JP4', 'JP5']
if fueltype in fueltype_list:
    print('fueltype is in the list')
```

I plan to use this in an arcade `When` statement similar to as follows, but the `Includes()` function isn't available:

```
var fueltype = $feature.fueltype
var fueltype_list = ['F24', 'JP10', 'JP4', 'JP5', 'JP7', 'JP8', 'JetA', 'JetA1', 'JPTS'];
When (Includes(fueltype_list, fueltype), "Aviation", "other")
```

The `Includes` function seems to be the arcade equivalent to "if value in list" that I am looking for.  However, the `Includes` function is not available in the list of functions.  I found it in the arcade playground function list, and it worked as expected.  However, I am writing an arcade expresion for Visualization in Portal, and it is not in the list of available functions.

[image]

Is there a different similar function that would be available in Visualizations arcade expressions?

Comment: Your original question did not state that it was for a specific profile. You need to provide such information. Maybe you can try the [IndexOf](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/data_functions/#indexof)? If it returns -1 then its not in the array.

Comment: `Includes` is available in [Portal 1.12](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/guide/release-notes/#version-112)

Answer (score 1):

You could use Decode() as a workaround.

```
var fueltype = $feature.fueltype
var decodedFuel = Decode(fueltype,
    'F24', "Aviation",
    'JP10',"Aviation",
    'JP4', "Aviation",
    'JP5', "Aviation",
    'JP7', "Aviation",
    'JP8', "Aviation",
    'JetA',"Aviation",
    'JetA1',"Aviation",
    'JPTS',"Aviation",
    "other")
```